# reactjs pop up opened and closed while re-rendering the parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, signalr, bootstrap-modal, react-dnd

I am trying to simulate the Trello board, with reactjs and signalR (.netCore).
I created the board with list of cards and each card item has card details which is a pop up.
that card details pop up opens when the user clicks on the card title. I am using signalR (Websocket) to make multiusers interact within the same board by listening to an event which re-render the whole board when any user change a card.
The issue happens when :
User A is Opening the pop up modal for task 1 and user B is dragging task 2 from todo card list to the in progress card list for example.
when that action happened the pop up close and open again as the whole trello board was rerendered based on the event that each user is listening to.
How can I fix that opening closing issue with the pop up an keep it open as it's ??
and if the logic is wrong please feel free to inform me!

note: I am using react-beautiful-dnd package for the drag and drop feature.

**Trello Board**

```
 <DragDropContext
      onDragEnd={(result) => {
        ondragend(result);
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          {
            sprintLoading ?
              sprints.map((card, index) => (
                // our sprints 
                <TrelloList
                  sprintType={card.sprintType}
                  index={index}
                  listId={card.sprintId}
                  sprintSchemaId={card.sprintSchemaId}
                  key={card.sprintId}
                  title={card.sprintName}
                  cards={card.tasks}
                />
              ))
              : null
          }
    </DragDropContext >
  );
}
```

**Trello List**

```
    useEffect(async () => {
        
    }, [tasks, socketState, trelloRerender]);
    return (
        <Droppable droppableId={String(listId)} >
            {(provided) => (
                <div
                    {...provided.droppableProps}
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    style={styles.container}>
                    <h4>{title}</h4>
                    {cards ? cards.map((card, index) =>
                    (
                        // our tasks

                            <TrelloCard
                                sprintType={sprintType}
                                listId={listId}
                                index={index}
                                cardId={card.taskId}
                                key={card.taskId}
                                text={card.taskDescription}
                                projectId={card.projectId}
                                userId={card.userId}
                                sprintId={card.sprintId}
                                sprintSchemaId={card.sprintSchemaId}
                                title={card.taskName}
                                schemaId={card.sprintSchemaId}
                                groupId={card.groupId}
                                taskStatus={card.taskStatus}
                                userName={card.user ? card.user.userName : ''}
                                taskCreatedDate={card.taskCreatedDate}
                                taskDueDate={card.taskDueDate}
                                comments={card.comments}
                            />

                    )) : null}
                    {provided.placeholder}
                </div>
            )}
        </Droppable>
    )
};
```

**Trello card**

```
    const { showTaskDetails, setShowTaskDetails } = useContext(ShowTaskDetailsContext);

 useEffect(async () => {
        await axios.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/tasks/${cardId}`).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.comments);
            setCurrentTaskComments(res.data.comments)
            console.log(currentTaskComments);
        });
    }, [rerenderForComments]);

    useEffect(async () => {
        const sprintId = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
        setRerenderforCards(false);
        setSprintId(sprintId);
        setIsRolledback(false);
        await fetchObject(`${BACKEND_URL}/sprintschemas/${sprintSchemaId}`)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.sprintTaskRollback !== null) {
                    setIsRolledback(true);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, []);
const handleShowTaskDetails = () => setShowTaskDetails(true);
const handleCloseTaskDetails = () => setShowTaskDetails(false);
    

   return (
        <Draggable draggableId={String(cardId)} index={index} key={cardId} >
            {provided => (
                // as provided.innerdiv need to refer to an action DOM node and card is a material-ui node 
                <div
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                    {...provided.dragHandleProps} >
                    <Card style={styles.cardContainer}  >
                        {/*  testing generic hooks */}
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography component={'div'}
                                gutterBottom>
                                <span
                                    // href={`/loboard/${sprintId}`}
                                    style={{ display: "block", fontWeight: "bold" }}
                                    onClick={handleShowTaskDetails}
                                >
                                    {title}
                                </span>
                                <TrelloCardDetails
                                    showTaskDetails={showTaskDetails}
                                    handleCloseTaskDetails={handleCloseTaskDetails}
                                    title={title}
                                    description={text}
                                    comments={currentTaskComments}
                                    assignto={userName}
                                    cardId={cardId}
                                    handleDropDownchanged={handleDropDownchanged}
                                    handleMarkCompleted={handleMarkCompleted}
                                    markCompletedBtnTxt={markCompletedBtnTxt}
                                    markBtnStyle={markBtnStyle}
                                    userId={userId}
                                    setComments={setCurrentTaskComments}
                                    rerenderForComments={rerenderForComments}
                                    setRerenderForcommented={setRerenderForcommented}
                                />

                                {/*  onchange == move task to it's new list of cards */}
                                <Form.Group className="mt-2" controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect2">
                                    <Form.Row>
                                        <Form.Label column="sm" sm={4}>Move to:</Form.Label>
                                        <Col>
                                            {/* adding default value to reset  */}
                                            <Form.Control size="sm" as="select"
                                                onChange={handleDropDownchanged}
                                                defaultValue={'select'}
                                            >
                                                <option disabled value="select">select status</option>
                                                <option value="backlog" name='setBacklog'>backlog</option>
                                                <option value="todo" name='setTodo'>todo</option>
                                                <option value="inprogress" name='setInProgress'>inprogress</option>
                                                <option value="done" name='setInProgress'>done</option>
                                            </Form.Control>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Form.Row>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group>
                                    <Form.Row>
                                        <Form.Label column="sm" sm={4}>assigned to:</Form.Label>
                                        <Col>
                                            <Form.Control
                                                type="text"
                                                disabled
                                                value={userName} />
                                        </Col>
                                    </Form.Row>
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Row>
                                    <Button className={markBtnStyle}
                                        onClick=
                                        {() =>
                                            handleMarkCompleted(cardId)
                                        }
                                        style={{ display: "block" }}
                                    >
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                            <path d="M10.97 4.97a.75.75 0 0 1 1.07 1.05l-3.99 4.99a.75.75 0 0 1-1.08.02L4.324 8.384a.75.75 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.094 2.093 3.473-4.425a.267.267 0 0 1 .02-.022z" />
                                        </svg>
                                        {markCompletedBtnTxt}
                                    </Button>
                                </Row>
                                {/* <Row>
                                    <Col> */}
                                <span className="text-sm float-right mt-2">
                                    <small title="created at" className="text-muted d-block ">
                                        <BsCalendar />  {taskCreatedDate.split('T')[0]}
                                    </small>
                                </span>
                               
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </Card>
                </div>
            )}
        </Draggable>
    )
```

**Card details component**

```
export const TrelloCardDetails = ({
    showTaskDetails,
    description,
    comments,
    title,
    handleCloseTaskDetails
    , assignto, cardId,
    handleDropDownchanged,
    handleMarkCompleted,
    markBtnStyle,
    markCompletedBtnTxt,
    userId,
    setComments, rerenderForComments,
    setRerenderForcommented
}) => {
    useEffect(() => {   
        console.log("card details")
    }, [comments]);
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal
                show={showTaskDetails}
                onHide={handleCloseTaskDetails}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>{title}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form.Group className="mt-2" controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect2">
                        <Form.Row>
                            <Form.Label column="sm" sm={4}>Move to:</Form.Label>
                            <Col>
                                {/* adding default value to reset  */}
                                <Form.Control size="sm" as="select"
                                    onChange={handleDropDownchanged}
                                    defaultValue={'select'}
                                >
                                    <option disabled value="select">select status</option>
                                    <option value="backlog" name='setBacklog'>backlog</option>
                                    <option value="todo" name='setTodo'>todo</option>
                                    <option value="inprogress" name='setInProgress'>inprogress</option>
                                    <option value="done" name='setInProgress'>done</option>
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Col>
                        </Form.Row>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Row>
                            <Form.Label column="sm" sm={4}>assigned to:</Form.Label>
                            <Col>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    disabled
                                    value={assignto} />
                            </Col>
                        </Form.Row>
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Row>
                            <Form.Label column="sm" sm={4}>Description: </Form.Label>
                            <Col>
                                <Form.Control style={{ resize: 'none' }} as="textarea" value={description} disabled />
                            </Col>
                        </Form.Row>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Row>
                        <Button
                            className={markBtnStyle}
                            onClick=
                            {() =>
                                handleMarkCompleted(cardId)
                            }
                            style={{ display: "block" }}
                        >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M10.97 4.97a.75.75 0 0 1 1.07 1.05l-3.99 4.99a.75.75 0 0 1-1.08.02L4.324 8.384a.75.75 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.094 2.093 3.473-4.425a.267.267 0 0 1 .02-.022z" />
                            </svg>
                            {markCompletedBtnTxt}
                        </Button>
                    </Row>

                    {/* <div style={{marginTop:"20px", backgroundColor: "#e9ecef", opacity: "1", border: "1px solid #ced4da", borderRadius: "5px" }}> */}

                    <CommentList rerenderForComments={rerenderForComments} setRerenderForcommented={setRerenderForcommented} assignto={assignto} comments={comments} setComments={setComments} taskId={cardId} userId={userId} />

                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>

                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleCloseTaskDetails}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleCloseTaskDetails}>
                        Save Changes
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>


        </div >
    );
}
```

Comment: Where is `showTaskDetails` updated and initialized?

Comment: @gpichot done edited. I am adding it with a context
sorry I dropped it while trying to minimize the code as much as possible to not be so much to read.